# difference between admin and cms - django

Tags: django, content-management-system, admin

If my question is too simple and dumb, please dont downvote.

I want to know the difference between django admin page and django cms. From what I understand, both do almost the same thing, don't they? Can someone please tell me the distinction between the two and why I need them. I am losing the overview now not knowing what to take, because I am creating a bigger project now, my understanding is:

In ADMIN: i can add new pages or delete them,

In CMS: i can edit the content of those pages.

Am I right?

Comment: please dont close the topic, it is also useful for others

Comment: A question on how to boil eggs would be useful to others, but off-topic here. This is not a programming question.

Comment: Yes, they should all be closed our migrated to the web dev site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django admin, on it's own, is not a full-fledged Content Management System. Yes, it will allow you to perform C.R.U.D. operations on your models, etc. If you had a "Page" model, you could crud pages, the same as DjangoCMS - sort of.

Django-CMS is built on top of Django admin to give you features specifically designed for Content Management: build  a navigational hierarchy, crud content, manage content types (Django-CMS calls these "Plugins"), provide an editorial workflow, manage permissions for pages, etc.

[Shameless Plug]

Most of the projects I build for freelance clients have a content management aspect, and Django-CMS provides an excellent "base" application on top of which, you can build custom functionality. It's very easy to extend, and I've yet to encounter a situation that Django-CMS couldn't handle.

Comment: You're welcome. I've had a tremendous amount of success with Django-CMS. It's one of the easiest to work with CMSes I've used.

Comment: wow, really? cool, then let me ask you if i have problems in the future :)

Comment: Feel free to ask me questions any time. I've worked with Django-CMS since shortly after it was released.

Comment: that is great. i am now launching a big webproject, you are my rescuer in the background for django-cms :D. thanks dude